# C# .net: distinguishing between a direct serial connection and a usb-to-serial connection

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, port, virtual

I have a question regarding serial ports in .NET

I am using SerialPort.GetPortNames() to get a list of port names

Is there any way to distinguish between virtual com ports and non-virtual ports?

Comment: No. Virtual ports are meant to simulate exactly a native one so they are recognized to every software even the old ones.

Comment: Why would you want/need to distinguish between them? Perhaps you're trying to solve a problem at the wrong level here?

Comment: I've been asked to distinguish between usb-to-serial communication to the application and direct serial communication

Answer (score 0):

For some USB devices you can do it indirectly reading info from Windows registry:

Enumerated USB serial devices can be found here:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Serenum\Enum

The specific COM port name for this USB device:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_067B&PID_2303\5&dc4a972&0&14\Device Parameters

In the example above, the string "VID_067B&PID_2303\5&dc4a972&0&14" belongs to a Prolific USB-to-Serial device.